# Analytic solution to the one-compartment model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following linear system of ordinary differential equations:

$$\frac {dA} {dt} = -k_a \cdot A$$
$$\frac {dC} {dt} = k_a \cdot A - k_0 \cdot C$$

$$A(0) = A_0$$
$$C(0) = 0$$

Some people may recognize this as the one-compartment model of pharmacokinetics, which describes the amount of a drug in the gut $A(t)$ and blood $C(t)$ over time when a pill with an amount of drug $A_0$  is taken, which is then absorbed from the gut into the blood with rate constant $k_a$ and eliminated from blood with rate constant $k_0$. But understanding the biology is not necessary for solving the problem.

When I consult [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dC%2Fdt+%3D+a+*+A0+*+exp%28-a*t%29+-+b+*+C+with+C%280%29%3D0) or pharmacology texts, they give this analytic solution to the problem:

$$A(t) = A_0 \cdot e^{-k_a \cdot t}$$
$$C(t) = \frac{A_0 \cdot k_a \cdot (e^{-k_a \cdot t}-e^{-k_0 \cdot t})}{k_0-k_a}$$

The problem is that this solution for $C(t)$ is undefined when $k_a$ is equal to $k_0$, though there obviously exists a solution to the differential equations when this is the case. I could solve for the special case of equality, but that still leaves the equation numerically unstable when the two parameters are close.

The [following plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C%3Dk1*e%5E-k0*%28e%5E%28-k1%29-e%5E%28-k0%29%29%2F%28k0-k1%29+from+k0%3D0+to+k0%3D2+and+k1%3D0+to+k1%3D2) illustrates the hole. If we set $t=1$ and plot $C(t)$ versus $k0$ and $ka$, then we see the line at $k0=ka$ where the function is not defined:

[image: Plot of k0 and ka versus C when t1=0]

Is there a solution to this system of equations that avoids the singularity?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can solve the first equation:

$$\frac {dA} {dt} = -k_a \cdot A \Rightarrow A(t) = A_0e^{-k_at},$$

having posed that $A(0) = k_0$. Then, solve the second equation imposing $k_0 = k_a$:

$$\frac {dC} {dt} = - k_a \cdot C + k_a A_0e^{-k_at}.$$

The general solution is $C_g(t) = Me^{-k_at}$, for some $M$. The particular solution should normally be in the form $C_p(t) = Ne^{-k_at}$, too. But since the general solution is similar, then

$$C_p(t) = Nte^{-k_at},$$

and

$$C(t) = Me^{-k_at} + Nte^{-k_at}.$$

Then:

$$C(0) = M = 0,$$

and
$$\frac {dC} {dt} = Ne^{-k_at}-Ntk_ae^{-k_at} = -Ntk_ae^{-k_at} + k_aA_0e^{-k_at}.$$

Hence, $N=k_a A_0$ and your unique solution is $C(t) = k_a A_0 te^{-k_at}$

**Another way...**

Consider the following:

$$\lim_{k_a \to k_0}\frac{A_0 \cdot k_a \cdot (e^{-k_a \cdot t}-e^{-k_0 \cdot t})}{k_a-k_0} = \lim_{k_a \to k_0}\frac{A_0 \cdot k_a \cdot e^{-k_a \cdot t} (1-e^{(k_a-k_0) \cdot t})}{k_a-k_0} =\\= A_0 k_0 t e^{-k_a \cdot t} ,$$

since

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{-xt}}{x} = t$$

Comment: Right, that's the solution when $k_a$ equals $k_0$. Is there a solution that is applicable both when they are equal and when they are not equal?

Comment: I mean besides the obvious--combining them in a piecewise function to plug the hole.

Comment: I think the limit is what you are looking for.

Comment: The solution derived from the limit is still only applicable when $k_a$ and $k_0$ are equal. Maybe such a thing does not exist, but I am looking for a single formula that works for both cases. The main reason is numeric; if $k_a$ and $k_0$ are very close but not equal then computing $k_0-k_a$ will have huge round-off error. Maybe I should add a "numerical analysis" tag.

Comment: This is an intrinsic property of this function. Think about $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. Normally, this function is defined as the $sinc(x)$ and is assumed that $sinc(0) = 1$, in order to make it continuous.

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Comment: specifically, why you want a general formula and not a piecewise one? Maybe this can help us to help you!

Comment: Perhaps this makes this question more suitable for cstheory, but a piecewise solution is not numerically stable near the plugged hole.